# Looking for a light substitute for OBS

Tags: windows, video, webcam

I am looking for a webcam streamer with a cropping functionality (so it can get the webcam input, crop it and stream to a virtual cam) + audio/video recording option, free and lighter than OBS. So any small or simple software with those options will be worth trying for me.

Comment: What OS must it run on? And how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions?

Comment: windows 10. how much? depends on how sure I am that it won't crush on 4GB PC as my OBS crushes during recordings....